# Angular 2, gives cannot read property 'length' of undefined while calling a function from another components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a components (Lets say A) with `@input` decorator to get the values from the selector. This component will create
text fields based on the `@input` values given in the selector. The A component is being used in another component (Lets say B)
B component is having the A component selector and also a button. On click of the button I am calling a function (Lets say `GetData`).
Inside the `GetData` function am calling the function (lets say `getValues`) from A component by creating an object for the A component.
While click on the `GetData` function it calls the `getValues` function from the component which throws the console error as  gives cannot read property 'length' of undefined
Please help me to resolve this issue thanks in advance

**Component A**

```
 import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
        selector: 'my-comp',
        templateUrl: '<form #f="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="let iter of arr(num).fill(1);let i=index">
    <input type="text" name="textValue{{i}}" ngModel   #textValue="ngModel" [id]="'textValue' + i">
    </div>
    </form>'
    })
    export class MyCompComponent {
        @ViewChildren('textValue') inputs;
        public myData:any=[];
        @Input('iterNumber') iterNum: number;
        arr = Array;
        num: number;

        ngOnInit() {
            this.num = this.iterNum;
        }
    getValues() {
        debugger
        for(var i=0;i<this.inputs.length;i++){
          this.myData.push(this.inputs._results[i].viewModel)
        }
             console.log(this.myData)
    }
}
```

**Component B**

```
import { MyCompComponent } from '../my-comp/my-comp.component';
import { Component, Input,Directive } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: '<my-comp [iterNumber]=3></my-comp>
<button type="button" (click)="getValues()">GetValues</button>'
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public getValueList:any;
  constructor(public cmpnt:MyCompComponent){

  }
  getData(){
    this.cmpnt.getValues();
  }
}
```

**Error in Console**

EXCEPTION:

> Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:1:0
>   caused by: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Have you tried initializing inputs with an empty array?

Comment: yep done no use

Comment: i suggest checking out the component interaction section in the angular documentation. Where there are multiple techniques for making components interact with each other https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 1):

A component is *not* an injectable [provider](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Provider-type-alias.html). It cant be injected into another component.

Just remove the parameter here:

```
 constructor(public cmpnt:MyCompComponent){

  }
```

and use view child.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild(MyCompComponent)
  public cmpt:any;

  public getValueList:any;

 //..
    getData(){
    this.cmpnt.getValues();
  }
```

Comment: nothing worked, but previous length error is not coming but am getting Cannot read property 'push' of undefined, have any idea

Comment: your ViewChild gave me some idea, now its working after some alteration to the code thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your html code for example you used multiple `name` attributes in your `input`.

Please look at https://codepen.io/souldreamer/pen/QydMNG where they made something similar (this is not written by me).

Hope this helps.

Comment: check now I have edited the question, your code pen is not working please check it